# Does APEX have a limit column for PDF files?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Ive been working on Oracle Apex 4.2. 
The deal is that I have some information I want to save into a PDF file. They're 26 fields to be exactly but the issue is that once I open the PDF file it doesn't works, says: "There was a problem loading the PDF file".

Something I tried  in the Print Attributes section is to disable one single field and click on recalculate columns (4 width point for each field, before on that was 3 point for each field). And now the PDF works! But once I enable the remaining field it doesn't works.

Does Apex have a 25 column limit? or something like that? Been searching and trying for at least 3 days.